# There is a problem when I return my value to html, 1 is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html

I get an error that 1 is not defined, does anyone know why? I can't seem to find my mistake.
The error is about : `document.getElementById("return_data").innerHTML = BeerData[retu][1];`

```js
var BeerData = [
  ["Jupiler", 5.2],
  ["Cristal", 5],
  ["Stella Artois", 5.2],
  ["GOUDEN CAROLUS CLASSIC", 8.5],
  ["GOUDEN CAROLUS TRIPEL", 9],
  ["GOUDEN CAROLUS WHISKY INFUSED", 11.7],
  ["Duvel", 8.5],
  ["Duvel Tripel Hop", 9.5]
];

for (i = 0; i < BeerData.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("drinkList").innerHTML += "<option value='" + BeerData[i][0] + "'>" + BeerData[i][0] +"</option>";
}

function Button() {
  var retu;
  for (i = 0; i < BeerData.length; i++) {
    if (BeerData[i][1] == document.getElementById("drinkList").value) {
      retu = i;
    }
  }

  //return BeerData[retu][1];
  document.getElementById("return_data").innerHTML = BeerData[retu][1];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Button()"> Verzenden </button>

<!-- drink -->
<div class="form1">
  <input type="text" name="drink" id="drink" list="drinkList" autocomplete="off" required>
  <label for="drink" class="label-drink" >
    <span class="content-drink">Welke Drank?</span>
  </label>
 
  <datalist id="drinkList">   
  </datalist>
</div>

<p id="return_data"></p>
```

Comment: I haven't tested it, but just now I assume there are two problems:
1. In the if condition of your loop you probably have to check against `BeerData[i][0]`
2. if no option is selected, `retu` will be `undefined`
Apart from that, good practice would be to have a `break` statement in the loop once a match is found (if only one match can exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at play here:

1. With the comparison `if (BeerData[i][1] == document.getElementById("drinkList").value)`, you're not comparing the correct element of each `BeerData` element. You've created each `option` with a `value` from `BeerData[i][0]`, but then trying to compare it with `BeerData[i][1]` instead.
2. With the same comparison `if (BeerData[i][1] == document.getElementById("drinkList").value)`, you've also tried to get the `value` of the element with ID `drinkList`, which is the `datalist` element, and not the `input` whose value you're wishing to get. Instead you should target the `value` property of the element you've assigned the `drink` ID to.

```js
var BeerData = [
  ["Jupiler", 5.2],
  ["Cristal", 5],
  ["Stella Artois", 5.2],
  ["GOUDEN CAROLUS CLASSIC", 8.5],
  ["GOUDEN CAROLUS TRIPEL", 9],
  ["GOUDEN CAROLUS WHISKY INFUSED", 11.7],
  ["Duvel", 8.5],
  ["Duvel Tripel Hop", 9.5]
];

for (i = 0; i < BeerData.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("drinkList").innerHTML += "<option value='" + BeerData[i][0] + "'>" + BeerData[i][0] + "</option>";
}

function Button() {
  var retu;
  for (i = 0; i < BeerData.length; i++) {
    if (BeerData[i][0] == document.getElementById("drink").value) {
      retu = i;
    }
  }

  //return BeerData[retu][1];
  document.getElementById("return_data").innerHTML = BeerData[retu][1];

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <button onclick="Button()"> Verzenden </button>

  <!-- drink -->
  <div class="form1">
    <input type="text" name="drink" id="drink" list="drinkList" autocomplete="off" required>
    <label for="drink" class="label-drink">
                <span class="content-drink">Welke Drank?</span>
            </label>
    <datalist id="drinkList">   
            </datalist>
  </div>
  <p id="return_data"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were targeting index 1 which was numbers instead of the string in the drop down and secondly, you were fetch id of the data list which is just a label and cannot return selected value. However the value was being set to the input field so all you had to do was target the input field id.

```
 document.getElementById("drink").value
```

**Working Code:**

```js
var BeerData = [
    ["Jupiler", 5.2],
    ["Cristal", 5],
    ["Stella Artois", 5.2],
    ["GOUDEN CAROLUS CLASSIC", 8.5],
    ["GOUDEN CAROLUS TRIPEL", 9],
    ["GOUDEN CAROLUS WHISKY INFUSED", 11.7],
    ["Duvel", 8.5],
    ["Duvel Tripel Hop", 9.5]
];

for (i = 0; i < BeerData.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("drinkList").innerHTML += "<option value='" + BeerData[i][0] + "'>" + BeerData[i][0] +"</option>";
}
function Button() {
    var retu;
    for (i = 0; i < BeerData.length; i++) {
        console.log(BeerData[i][1]);
        if (BeerData[i][0] == document.getElementById("drink").value) {
            retu = i;
        }
    }
    console.log(BeerData[retu],document.getElementById("drink").value, retu)

    document.getElementById("return_data").innerHTML = BeerData[retu][1];

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      
       <button onclick="Button()"> Verzenden </button>
    
            <!-- drink -->
        <div class="form1">
            <input type="text" name="drink" id="drink" list="drinkList" autocomplete="off" required>
            <label for="drink" class="label-drink" >
                <span class="content-drink">Welke Drank?</span>
            </label>
            <datalist id="drinkList">   
            </datalist>
        </div>
    

 
        <p id="return_data"></p>
    </body>
```